# What is linux php exec status result 8 for userdel?

Tags: php, linux, exec, status

I wrote a program, parts of which manage system users.
Sometimes this command does not work:

```
$strCommand = "sudo /usr/sbin/userdel $strDSUuser";
$cmdResult1 = exec($strCommand, $cmdResult2, $cmdStatus);
```

The status code returned is 8.
The closest meaning for code 8 I have found is there is not enough storage space available, which is not true.
What is code 8 and is there a good code reference somewhere?  The one I found may not be correct (http://developer-paradize.blogspot.com/2013/10/what-does-php-exec-return-value-of-5.html)
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Process exit codes are not standardized, beyond 0 being used for success. In particular, process exit codes are *not* errno values.

Helpfully, though, [the man page for `userdel`](https://linux.die.net/man/8/userdel) has a section explaining what its exit codes are, including:

```
8
    user currently logged in
```